# Find service`s uuid of a bluetooth device

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bluetooth, winsock2

I'm trying to get information about services provided by bluetooth devices. Using `WSALookupServiceNext` I can get list of all services. However, regardless of what bluetooth device I try to discover, the resulting WSAQUERYSET structure (`pqs`) never contains `lpServiceClassId` field (while the `lpszServiceInstanceName` is always present). I want to know UUID of a service to determine to which class of the [Table 2: Service Class Profile Identifiers](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery/) it belongs.

```
#include<winsock2.h>

int main()
{
    WSADATA data;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);

    WSAQUERYSET qs{};
    qs.dwSize = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);
    qs.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
    qs.dwNumberOfCsAddrs = 0;
    qs.lpszContext = (LPWSTR)L"12:34:56:78:99:11";
    qs.lpServiceClassId = const_cast<LPGUID>(&PublicBrowseGroupServiceClass_UUID);

    const DWORD flags = LUP_FLUSHCACHE | LUP_RETURN_ALL;
    HANDLE hlookup = nullptr;
    WSALookupServiceBegin(&qs, flags, &hlookup);
    while (true) {
        char buff[4096];
        WSAQUERYSET* pqs = (WSAQUERYSET*)buff;
        DWORD size = sizeof(buff);
        memset(buff, 0, size);

        const INT res = WSALookupServiceNext(hlookup, flags, &size, pqs);
        if (res != 0 && GetLastError() == WSA_E_NO_MORE) {
            break;
        }

        // it prints "service name=Advanced Audio, service uuid=0x0"
        wprintf(L"service name=%s, service uuid=0x%X\n", pqs->lpszServiceInstanceName, pqs->lpServiceClassId->Data1);
    }
}
```

Comment: First at all set lpServiceClassId to L2CAP_PROTOCOL_UUID. It allows to enumerate ALL services. Next, set Flags to LUP_RES_SERVICE | LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_RETURN_TYPE | LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_RETURN_COMMENT |LUP_RETURN_BLOB | LUP_FLUSHCACHE. It returns lpBlob with full SDP answer. And you can parse SDP to get correct services list and all the detailed information.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko, thank you for the comment. I have found a good example how to do it in Qt framework implementation: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtconnectivity.git/tree/src/bluetooth/qbluetoothservicediscoveryagent_win.cpp?h=5.15.0

Comment: Yeap, they do it right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:
In order to get service ID we have to parse SPD structures which are returned from `WSALookupServiceNext` function call and accessible via `WSAQUERYSET.lpBlob` member.
For more details see [Mike Petrichenko's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61943884/find-services-uuid-of-a-bluetooth-device#comment109560430_61943884).
Also, there is a very good example how to implement it from [Qt framework source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtconnectivity.git/tree/src/bluetooth/qbluetoothservicediscoveryagent_win.cpp?h=5.15.0).

As for myself, I decided not to follow this path, because my goal was to write a console utility for pairing Bluetooth devices. I have found that there is a better way to do that using [Windows.Devices.Enumeration API](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing). Finally, using this API, I managed to create the [BluetoothDevicePairing](https://github.com/PolarGoose/BluetoothDevicePairing) utility I was working on.

Comment: Hi, you could also feel free to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) to end this thread and help people with the same issue.